# I create a Raspberry Pi Pico C project but get errors

Tags: c, build, raspberry-pi-pico

When I installed Visual Studio Code, tools and examples I used [the one click installer](https://github.com/raspberrypi/pico-setup-windows/releases/) and everything worked. I want to develop my own project.

1. I copied the blink folder to my new folder "blink" outside examples folder. New blink.c file has a red line on `#include "pico/stdlib.h"`. When I hover over it I get:

   > #include errors detected based on information provided by the configurationProvider setting.  Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit (C:\JasonStuff\myStuff\blink\blink.c).C/C++(1696) cannot open source file "pico/stdlib.h"C/C++(1696)
2. I copied the blink folder to my new folder "blink2" inside examples folder. New blink.c file has a red line on first character of the file. When I hover over it I get:

   > command-line error: language modes specified are incompatible   C/C++(1027)

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
project(blink)
add_executable(blink blink.c )
target_link_libraries(blink pico_stdlib)
pico_add_extra_outputs(blink)
example_auto_set_url(blink)
```

settings.json:

```
{
    "cmake.configureOnOpen": true,

    "cmake.configureEnvironment": {
        "PICO_SDK_PATH": "..\\..\\pico-sdk"
    },

    "cmake.preferredGenerators": [
        "NMake makefiles"
    ],
    "C_Cpp.default.configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cmake-tools"
}
```

Comment: Apart from the error, for simplicity, when I worked on the RPI Pico, I used Arduino IDe to generate, compile, build and download on the device and for writing, I used VsCode as an external editor.